# AWK: Average of each row from different measurement series

Tags: awk

My objective is to calculate the average of the second column from multiple measurement series (the average of the first row of K blocks, the average of the second row of K blocks etc.). All data is contained in one file and is seperated in blocks with a blank line. The file has the following structure:

```
#
#
33  -0.23
34.5  -0.32
36  -0.4
.
.
.

#
#
33  -0.25
34.5  -0.31
36  -0.38
.
.
.
```

Comment: You are not expecting other users here to write the actual code for you, aren't you? Please provide your current efforts and explain what makes you problems here. A good starting point should be a (minimal example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat avg.awk
BEGIN { FS=" " }
/^#/ { next }
/^\s*$/ { print col1/nr " " col2/nr; col1=col2=nr=0; next }
{ col1 += $1; col2 += $2; nr++ }
END {print col1/nr " " col2/nr }
```

with input:

```
$ cat test.txt
#
#
33  -0.23
34.5    -0.32
36  -0.4

#  
#
33  -0.25
34.5  -0.31
36  -0.38
```

gives as result:

```
$ awk -f avg.awk test.txt
34.5 -0.316667
34.5 -0.313333
```

Comment: like @romanperekhrest (and others) say(s): make your question - complete - . Show your expected output, what you think the solution should be. That way you'll get a fitting answer more swiftly.

Comment: @FredrikPihl Read my comment. And look at OP's history. I tried to help him and try to pass him a message for his next question.

Comment: I know, I'm just getting tired of all "give me the code" questions lately :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl me too. I'm on the verge of starting to downvote answers to question that don't have input, output and an attempt. I **really** wish there was a template for questions that required all 3.